# Rigorous version of the Symmetry of Things

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, symmetry, tiling, tessellations

I’m reading through The Symmetry of Things and I love it, but some of the arguments are handwavey and it’s hard for me to know if I fully understand. I’m curious if there is a rigorous reference that covers wallpaper groups and symmetries of sphere and the plane.

Comment: There’s some discussion of these in Artin’s *Algebra* if I remember correctly

Comment: Hermann Weyl "Symmetry" https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0691023743 +==+ H. S. M. Coxeter "Introduction to Geometry" https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0471504580